# Javac not on path when running maven with the zinc incremental compiler (scala maven plugin) as a service

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, javac

I'm a big fan of the zinc incremental compiler used by the maven scala plugin, but I found it annoying to have to start it up manually each time I bounce my laptop.  I wrote a script to run it as a service in Ubuntu - it starts up okay but when I run mvn install I get an error stating that it can not find the program javac.  Below is my script in /etc/init.d - NOTE: I specify the $JAVA_HOME and add it to the path in /etc/bash.bashrc which is explicitly sourced in this script.

```
#!/bin/bash

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          zinc
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start compiler at boot time
# Description:       Starts and stops the zinc incremental compiler
### END INIT INFO

source /etc/bash.bashrc
PROG_PATH="/opt/zinc/bin"
PROG="zinc" 

start() {
    su - gary "-c $PROG_PATH/$PROG -start 2>&1 >/dev/null &"
    echo "$PROG started"
}

stop() {
    su - gary "-c $PROG_PATH/$PROG -shutdown 2>&1 >/dev/null &"   
    echo "$PROG stopped"
}

## Check to see if we are running as root first.
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        exit 0
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
        exit 0
    ;;
    reload|restart|force-reload)
        stop
        start
        exit 0
    ;;
    **)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|reload}" 1>&2
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Zinc comes with -java-home command parameter. Have you tried that one?